# Copy syntax-coloured code block as rtf in intelliji IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, copy-paste

Is there a simple way to copy syntax-coloured code block as rtf in intellij IDEA?

Comment: What platform? If I copy the syntax colored text into wordpad and save as rtf on windows the colors stay what they are.

Comment: Are you sure user404? I've done the same on Windows XP using latest IDEA community edition and pasted syntax-colored text into Wordpad and MS Word and just a plain text showed up

Comment: make FR in IDEA tracker http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-67767

Comment: Fixed in 138.834 (IDEA 14 EAP), yay!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**UPDATE**: there is now a new plug-in for this: ['Copy' on steroids](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7198) that is maintained by JetBrains.

---

There is no way to copy colored code block from IDEA directly.

A workaround is to use **File | Export to HTML**, then open HTML in a browser, then copy from the browser window and paste into Wordpad or MS Word.

Another and more faster way is to install the [Copy as HTML](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=190) plug-in in **Settings | Plugins**:

> Copies a snippet of code as html
>
> - Adds menu items "Copy as HTML" to main menu and editor popup. Will copy the current selection or the complete editor buffer. Currently only works if focus is in editor (for example won't work in project tree).
> - Preserves more formatting than the built-in HTML export.
> - HTML is only a snippet (without html and body tags) meant to be inserted into a complete HTML document.
> - Currently HTML format is fixed and uses CSS a lot.
> - Options: unindent, add border, padding, line numbers, tabs to spaces conversion, include editor's warning and error highlighting (see IDE Settings -> Copy as HTML).
> - Reuses the editor "Show Line Numbers" setting (see Idea's "View" menu).

Comment: thanks, i know this way, but i prefer using such method: 1) copy to notepad++ 2) apply syntax highlighting 3) copy with nppexport plugin to clipboard as rtf

Comment: If you knew this method, plus another method, you should have replied yourself and accepted the reply as correct.

Comment: The Version of the plugin linked doesn't work with IDEA11.  A fixed version is available at:  http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-8163  I didn't edit CrazyCoder's answer because his URL still points to the official build where this fix should eventually be merged into.

Comment: Both JetBrains and Copy as HTML plugins work with 12, and both are nice, but I prefer JetBrain's output. They're slick.

Comment: Neither of these seem to work with IntelliJ 12 or 13 and Keynote 6. This is the only solution I found that works: https://gist.github.com/jimbojsb/1630790

Comment: @MattRaible, that was very useful. And there is a `darcula` theme for highlight [**here**](https://gist.github.com/jvandijk/395f4a41cc56955fee0a) which, in my limited tests, worked quite well. I copied that to `/usr/local/Cellar/highlight/3.30/share/highlight/themes/` and then used something like this `highlight -lO rtf -s darcula -k 'Courier' -K 11 input.sql > output.rtf` (For description of the options see [**this**](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/08/beautiful-presentations-with-highlight/) )

Answer (score 9):

**IntelliJ IDEA 15**

By default, you can copy rich text from IntelliJ to Microsoft Word (for example).

This feature can be found in **File > Settings... > Editor > General > Rich-text copy > Copy as rich text by default**

[image]

You can also change the color scheme only for the copy-paste operation (your current scheme won't be affected).

Comment: @popalka This should be the accepted answer, since the current one is outdated.

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to https://gist.github.com/
2. Copy code from IntelliJ to the new private gist;
3. Save it, copy colorful code from the browser to wherever you want;
4. Delete the gist.

Answer (score 3):

Use external tool notepad++
1) copy code snippet to notepad++ 
2) apply syntax highlighting
3) copy with nppexport plugin to clipboard as rtf

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot up-vote this answer multiple times. nppexport  is fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a mac and like TextMate, here's a great way to copy styled code from TextMate: https://github.com/bblimke/copy-with-style-tmbundle

It's not as convenient as doing it directly from IntelliJ, but it's a bit more convenient than using gist or pastebin.  Also, unlike the Copy as HTML Plugin for IntelliJ, this solution actually works at the time of this writing.