# JetBrains RubyMine code MS Word export

Tags: rubymine

Is there a function in the RubyMine IDE to export the code in a Microsoft Word document while retaining the format (font-family, font-size, color etc.) from RubyMine?

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards, shub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4883770/104891).

You can then paste the rich formatted text into Microsoft Word.